# Trying to add show/hide logic for tab buttons

Tags: react-native, react-native-navigation

I'm trying to write logic to show / hide my tabs in my bottom tab navigation in react-nativation (v5).

I've got this kinda working using the `tabBarButton` property, but for some reason I loose all the styling and they all bunch up to the left.

Here's my code for the bottom tab navigator:

```
const Tab = createBottomTabNavigator();

<NavigationContainer>
  <Tab.Navigator screenOptions={({ route }) => ({
    tabBarButton: (props) => {
      if (route.name == 'CalendarMain') {
        return null;
      }
      return (<TouchableWithoutFeedback {...props}/>);
    }
    >
    <Tab.Screen ... />
    <Tab.Screen ... />
    <Tab.Screen ... />
   </Tab.Navigator>
 </NavigationContainer>
```

As I say, it works, but the buttons are all pushed up to the left:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can get active screen in your CalendarMain screen component. Then set it to your redux store. After that connect navigator to redux and if your current screen is CalendarMain - return navigator without tabs, else - with all your tabs.
For example:

```
if(props.screen == 'CalendarMain'){
  return (
   <Tab.Navigator ...></Tab.Navigator>
  );
else return (
   <Tab.Navigator ...>
     <Tab.Screen ... />
     <Tab.Screen ... />
     <Tab.Screen ... />
   </Tab.Navigator>
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Aha, I got it in the end. The key is that you either want to return `null` (don't render a tab item), or `undefined` (it's undefined, so use the normal component). This looks like this:

```
      <Tab.Navigator screenOptions={({ route }) => ({
        tabBarVisible: true,
        tabBarButton: route.name === 'UsersMain' ? () => { return null; } : undefined,
```